# Issue with Reseller API - To be able to purchase Google Apps, please accept the following Term of service

Tags: api, google-reseller-api

I am trying to create new subscription using reseller API. But getting following exception - 
SEVERE: 412 OK
{
  "code" : 412,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "If-Match",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "To be able to purchase Google Apps, please accept the following Terms of Service .",
    "reason" : "conditionNotMet"
  } ],
  "message" : "To be able to purchase Google Apps, please accept the following Terms of Service ."
}
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 412 OK

Please suggest what I am missing ...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to enter your resell console and accept the Terms of Service

Answer (score 0):

Due to a current bug, you will need to visit the "old reseller console" (there's a link in the lower left corner of the reseller console to do this).  Once you visit the old reseller console, you'll be prompted for the ToS.